# getJSON jquery doesn't work with URL but works with file.json

Tags: jquery, json

I can not reach the data mins and price through url, but i can do it through file on my server. https://api.binance.com/api/v3/avgPrice?symbol=BNBUSDT

```html
    <!DOCTYPE>
         <html>
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
        <head>
          <title>getJson example</title>
           <script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
          integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
          
          
          <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
           $(document).ready(function() {
              $("button").click(function(event){
                  $.getJSON("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/avgPrice?symbol=BNBUSDT", function(price) {
                     $("#getJsonDiv").html('<p> mins: ' + price.mins + '</p>');
                     $("#getJsonDiv").append('<p>price: ' + price.price+ '</p>');
                  });
              });
           });
        </script>
        
        
        </head>
        <body>
          <div id="getJsonDiv">
         jQuery ajax getJSON example
          </div>
          <button>Get country data</button>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Could be a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSDidNotSucceed) problem, please check the browser console!

Comment: 100% a CORS problem. Look at the error in the console.

Comment: do you guys know how to solve it?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-doesn-t-postman-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on

Comment: There's no way to solve it client side. You will have to make the cal from your server instead.